# improve document classification method

Tags: python, machine-learning, regression, libsvm, document-classification

I have a program to predict whether a news article is about a certain topic.

There is two main scripts:

1) bow_train.py - generates a wordlist and a model and stores them in two files (arab.model and wordList.pkl)

2) bow_predict.py - uses the wordlist and model to classify unknown articles

The method used is logistic regression instead of support vector machines since the performance of logistic regression for this kind of classification is supposed to be much better.

I want to improve the results. Is there another method that allows you to emphasize on certain keywords. For example, for the topic "Arab Spring" I would input a list of keywords : ["protests", "unrest", "revolution" etc] and files with these keywords will have a higher probability then those without.

**bow_predict.py**

```
import re
import os
import sys
import pickle
import operator

from collections import Counter

from liblinearutil import *

from bow_util import *

# path to directory with articles that should be classified
rootdirAll = 'C:\\Users\\Jiyda\\Desktop\\bow_arab\\all\\'

# load the wordList and model from the training phase
wordListIn = open('wordList.pkl', 'rb')

m        = load_model('arab.model')
wordList = pickle.load(wordListIn)

counterByFilepathAll = {}

# count and store term frequencies
for folder, subs, files in os.walk(rootdirAll):
    for filename in files:
        filepath       = os.path.join(folder, filename)
        wordsInArticle = get_words_from_file(filepath)
        counterByFilepathAll[filepath] = count_words(wordsInArticle)

denseData = []

# generate features from term frequencies (bag-of-words)
for _, counter in counterByFilepathAll.iteritems():
    denseData.append(gen_features(counter, wordList))

# assume output class is 1 (liblinear/libsvm always require a output class
# even for unknown data)
classList = [1 for _ in xrange(0, len(counterByFilepathAll))]

# predict using the model from training phase
y, x                  = classList, denseData
p_label, p_acc, p_val = predict(y, x, m)

# store probabilites by filepath
probByFilepath = {}
i = 0
for filepath, _ in counterByFilepathAll.iteritems():
    probByFilepath[filepath] = p_val[i]
    i += 1

# sort by probability
sortedByProb = sorted(probByFilepath.iteritems(),
                      key=operator.itemgetter(1),
                      reverse=True)

# write to output file         
probsOut = open('probsOut.txt', 'wb')
for t in sortedByProb:
    probsOut.write(' '.join(str(s) for s in t) + '\n')

probsOut.close()
```

**bow_train.py**

```
import re
import os
import sys
import copy
import pickle

from collections import defaultdict
from collections import Counter

from liblinearutil import *

from bow_util import *

# Initialize directories for articles

rootdirArab = sys.argv[1]
rootdirNoArab = sys.argv[2]

#rootdirArab   = 'C:\\Users\\Jiyda\\Desktop\\bow_arab\\arab\\'
#rootdirNoArab = 'C:\\Users\\Jiyda\\Desktop\\bow_arab\\no_arab\\'

wordSet                 = set()
counterByFilepathArab   = {}
counterByFilepathNoArab = {}

# generate set of all words in all articles
for rootdir in [rootdirArab, rootdirNoArab]:
    for folder, subs, files in os.walk(rootdir):
        for filename in files:
            filepath       = os.path.join(folder, filename)
            wordsInArticle = get_words_from_file(filepath)
            wordSet        = wordSet.union(wordSet, wordsInArticle)

# store sorted set in list
wordList = sorted(wordSet)

# save sorted list to output file for prediction phase
wordListOut = open('wordList.pkl', 'wb')
pickle.dump(wordList, wordListOut)

# count and store term frequencies for all arab spring training articles
for folder, subs, files in os.walk(rootdirArab):
    for filename in files:
        filepath       = os.path.join(folder, filename)
        wordsInArticle = get_words_from_file(filepath)
        counterByFilepathArab[filepath] = count_words(wordsInArticle)

# count and store term frequencies for all non arab spring training articles
for folder, subs, files in os.walk(rootdirNoArab):
    for filename in files:
        filepath       = os.path.join(folder, filename)
        wordsInArticle = get_words_from_file(filepath)
        counterByFilepathNoArab[filepath] = count_words(wordsInArticle)

# generate features. the features for one article are a list of the frequenices 
# of each term in wordList found in the article
denseData = []

for counter in counterByFilepathArab.values():
    denseData.append(gen_features(counter, wordList))

for counter in counterByFilepathNoArab.values():
    denseData.append(gen_features(counter, wordList))

# set output value to 1 for arab spring articles and -1 for non arab spring articles
classList = [1 for _ in xrange(0, len(counterByFilepathArab))] + \
            [-1 for _ in xrange(0, len(counterByFilepathNoArab))]

# train logistic regression model
y, x  = classList, denseData
prob  = problem(y, x)
# uncomment to obtain cross validation results
#param = parameter('-v 5')
m     = train(prob)#, param)

# store model in output file for prediction phase
save_model('arab.model', m)

# uncomment to check if training worked as expected
#p_label, p_acc, p_val = predict(y, x, m)
#ACC, MSE, SCC         = evaluations(y, p_label)

wordListOut.close()
```

Comment: I am not clear what your question really is.  SO is best for _specific_ questions.

Comment: Why do you want to artificially boost certain keywords?

If you really want to do it, you could try adding "fake" documents in the Arab-Spring test set that contain the terms that you want to boost.